# How do I access a class instance variable across class of same module?

Tags: ruby, class, module, scope, instance-variables

I need to access the config variables from inside another class of a module.

In test.rb, how can I get the config values from client.rb?  `@config` gives me an uninitialized var.  It's in the same module but a different class.

Is the best bet to create a new instance of config?  If so how do I get the argument passed in through run.rb?

Or, am I just structuring this all wrong or should I be using `attr_accessor`?

client.rb

```
module Cli
  class Client

    def initialize(config_file)
      @config_file = config_file
      @debug = false
    end

    def config
      @config ||= Config.new(@config_file)
    end

    def startitup
      Cli::Easy.test
    end
 end
end
```

config.rb

```
module Cli
  class Config
    def initialize(config_path)
      @config_path = config_path
      @config = {}
      load
    end

    def load
      begin
        @config = YAML.load_file(@config_path)
      rescue
        nil
      end
    end
  end
end
```

test.rb

```
module Cli
  class Easy
    def self.test
      puts @config
    end
  end
end
```

run.rb

```
client = Cli::Client.new("path/to/my/config.yaml")
client.startitup
```

Comment: If you want to access an instance attribute from outside the class, you need to provide an accessor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@config is a instance variable, if you want get it from outside you need to provide accessor, and  give to Easy class self object.

client.rb:

```
attr_reader :config
#...
def startitup
  Cli::Easy.test(self)
end
```

test.rb

```
def self.test(klass)
  puts klass.config
end
```

If you use @@config, then you can acces to this variable without giving a self object, with class_variable_get.

```
class Lol
  @@lold = 0
  def initialize(a)
    @@lold = a
  end
end
x = Lol.new(4)
puts Lol.class_variable_get("@@lold")
```

I recommend to you read metaprogramming ruby book.

Comment: thanks this led me to the answer to just pass config back through, kinda sucks to have to pass it across to every call to a class in the module.